# How to say custom message that the Email is unique from mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to say the custom message that the Email is unique from mongoose Schema. I do not want to check that this email exists or not from my back-end because I already said in mongoose schema that

```
email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please Enter your Email"],
    unique: [
      true,
      "Please use unique mail to create an account",
    ],
    validate: [validator.isEmail, "Please Enter a valid Email"],
  },
```

for getting this message from err. message in the console but instead of this I am getting this one : `"message": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: E-COMMERS_v1_Database.users index: email_1 dup key: { email: \"ej@gmail.com\" }",`

I know what is the meaning of this message but I set my custom message in

```
unique: [
      true,
      "Please use unique mail to create an account",
    ],
```

I want to get my message from mongoose/DB. How?? Is it the correct way to set a message?

Comment: Try making your own custom error handling & middleware instead of expecting error from mongoose database.

Comment: I can do it but I tried it from db. Because like we use required:[true,' and here our message and it's work'] => that's why I thought that it is possible in unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const signUp = async(req, res, next) => {
  const findOneEmail = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
  if (findOneEmail) {
    return next(AppError("This email already used")); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

We can solve it in regester controller or route whatever your js file from back end not from DBM. So we can write a statement in catch block:

```
if (e.message.includes("E11000")) {
  return res.status(500).json({
    message: "This Email Already Used try with another email",
    success: false,
  });
}
```

Or we can make our own error handler function

```
(err,req,res,next)=>{
  if (err.message.includes("E11000")) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      message: "This Email Already Used try with another email",
      success: false,
    });
  }
}
```

we can use the above error handler function multi-time for various errors with a different statements like

```
module.exports = (err, req, res, next) => {
  err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  err.message = err.message || "Internal Server Error";
  return res.status(err.statusCode).json({
    success: false,
    error: err.stack,
  });
};
```